# How to find momentum of different pieces of the same object after it explodes?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, explosions

If a stationery object explodes into a specific number of pieces due to internal force, how can I find the momentum of these pieces?

Comment: Use conservation of linear momentum and conservation of energy.

Comment: Recall that momentum is a vector. What is the total momentum of a system composed of two identical masses moving at the same speed in opposite directions?

Comment: But what if it explodes into more than two pieces with identical masses?

Comment: The other commenters seem to have missed your point.  You cannot *a priori* calculate the momentum of each piece without knowing its mass, location relative to the blast center, proportion of blast affecting it, and so on.  Alternatively, (joke), map the initial angle of ejection, measure the landing point, and you'll have an estimate of the initial momentum :-)

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+kinetic+energy+momentum+explosion